# How to redirect to another page in a Facebook application?

Tags: facebook

How do I redirect to another page in a Facebook application?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using fbjs then it's `document.setLocation('http://example.com');`

If you are using an iframe app then with javascript it's `window.top.location.href = 'http://example.com';`

and for an anchor tag:

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_top">Link text</a>
```

If you don't care about the browsers address bar changing and only the iframe being redirected then you can use standard links and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`document.setLocation('url');`